# Link on top level of dropdown menu? | Embed Google map?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I am currently building this site in Bootstrap: http://arrowtownlodge.co.nz/home.html

As you can see, I am using dropdown menus. Is there a way to have the top level of the menu lead to a generic page which then leads the viewer to the sub level pages? I have applied a link to the Golf menu but it does not open the desired page http://arrowtownlodge.co.nz/arrowtown_golf.html

My other question is about how to embed a Google  map showing the location. I have used my usual technique of an iframe but it does not load on my Contact page. What do I need to do?

Comment: so what you want for the menu is; when Golf menu is clicked. it should direct you to that page right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The Golf menu title should open the golf page, the same destination as the first sub menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this will make all your links in the menu work the way you want it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
       location.href = this.href;
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - would you mind telling me exactly where to add this code?

Comment: add it somewhere in your footer section